# Set the Message-ID mail header in Rails3 / ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, email-headers, rfc5322

I would like to alter the `Message-ID` header that is in the header portion of an email sent from a Ruby on Rails v3 application using ActionMailer.

I am using Sendmail on localhost for mail delivery.

Do I configure this in Sendmail or ActionMailer?

Where do I configure this (if it is ActionMailer):  a file in `config/` folder or a file in app/mailers/ folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out.  The easiest way to do is to use the `default` method at the top of the mailer class file.

Example:

```
require 'digest/sha2'
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default "Message-ID"=>"#{Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(Time.now.to_i.to_s)}@yourdomain.com"

  # ... the rest of your mailer class
end
```

However, I found this difficult to test, so I wrote a private method and used the `sent_at` time instead of `Time.now`:

```
def message_id_in_header(sent_at=Time.now)
  headers["Message-ID"] = "#{Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(sent_at.to_i.to_s)}@yourdomain.com"
end
```

And I simply called that method before calling the `mail` method.  This made it easy to pass a `sent_at` parameter from my test and verify a match in `email.encoded`.

Comment: If you actually want each message to have a different ID, you need to make the default a lamba. In the first block of code above, it calculates the message-ID once, at init, and uses the same one for every message. Argh, I'm trying to give some code here and StackOverflow won't let me format it. I'll just add another answer.

Comment: One issue with this approach is that if you send multiple emails per second, all of them will have the same message id

Answer (score 22):

Teddy's answer is good, except that if you actually want each message to have a different ID, you need to make the default a lambda. In the first block of code in his answer, it calculates the message-ID once, at init, and uses the same one for every message.

Here's how I'm doing this in my app:

```
default "Message-ID" => lambda {"<#{SecureRandom.uuid}@#{Rails.application.config.mailgun_domain}>"}
```

... with the domain taken from a custom app config variable (and using SecureRandom.uuid, which is a little more straightforward than a SHA-2 based on the timestamp IMO.)

Comment: btw - the message-id must be placed between "< >" - otherwise, it doesn't conform to the mail standard. So, the code will be: default "Message-ID" => lambda {"<#{SecureRandom.uuid}@#{Rails.application.config.mailgun_domain}>"}

Comment: Although this is mostly the right answer, I believe it should be edited to include <> as @andrewleung mentioned. Otherwise, it will be ignored. default "Message-ID" => lambda {"<#{SecureRandom.uuid}@#{Rails.application.config.mailgun_domain}>"}

Comment: in Ruby `1.9.3-p484` I had to add `|v|` to lambda to avoid an exception: `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

Comment: Thanks @sorens. My guess is this has less to do with the Ruby version and more to do with the Rails (ActionMailer) version. I think I was on Rails 3.2 when I did this.

Comment: @sorens Or use proc { ... } instead of lambda { |v| ... } ??   Not sure, but there is a suggestion that lambdas started to care about exact argument counts with Ruby 1.9, and at least current ActionMailer is passing in an object.

Comment: I prefer `SecureRandom.hex` , because it is shorter.

Comment: Since `Mail::Message` has a `message_id` attribute ([docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mail/Mail/Message#message_id-instance_method)), you can write `default message_id: -> { "my@id.com" }`. Angle brackets are added automatically.

Answer (score 8):

I usually prefer generating the message-id with a UUID. Assuming you have the uuid gem:

```
headers['Message-ID'] = "<#{ UUID.generate }@example.com>"
```

Also you should note that according to [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.4) the message-id should be placed inside "<" and ">"

Comment: I use the uuid gem a lot in other code.  That is a great suggestion.  It is better to use a UUID vs a SHA256 checksum of the current timestamp.

Comment: It seems since Ruby 1.9.3 you don't need a gem to do this:
`require 'securerandom'` followed by `SecureRandom.uuid`

Answer (score 6):

In Rails 4+ (or just Ruby 2.0+) the folowing syntax is working correctly:

```
default "Message-ID" => ->(v){"<#{Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(Time.now.to_i.to_s)}@yourdomain.com>"}
```

Tested this with MailCatcher.

Answer (score 3):

@jasoncrawford is almost right. The problem is that the mailgun_domain attribute may not be able at development environment, so it is better to access the ActionMailer configs.

```
default "Message-ID" => lambda {"<#{SecureRandom.uuid}@#{ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings[:domain]}>"}
```