# Set Email Message ID for Devise confirmation emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

All the devise confirmation emails are going to spam folders, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598343/set-the-message-id-mail-header-in-rails3-actionmailer) suggests I need to set the message-id for default `UserMailer`. How would i set the default for devise's confirmation emails?

This is the code to set it

```
require 'digest/sha2'
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default "Message-ID" => lambda {"<#{SecureRandom.uuid}@#{Rails.application.config.mailgun_domain}>"}

  # ... the rest of your mailer class
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patching the DeviseMailer should work

#### app/mailers/devise_mailer.rb

```
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  default "Message-ID" => lambda {"<#{SecureRandom.uuid}@#{Rails.application.config.mailgun_domain}>"}
  ## ...
end
```

#### config/initializers/devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer = 'DeviseMailer'
  # ...
end
```